# How to prevent flutter_webview from reloading rotatiting screen?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, pageviews, flutter-pageview

I'm using `webview_flutter`  plugin like below:

```
@override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
         return Scaffold(
            body: WebView(
                      gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
                      initialUrl: link,
                      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                      navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
                        return NavigationDecision.prevent;
                      },
                    )
         );
    }
```

And whenever I change the screen orientation the pageView reloads the webPage.
How can I prevent this reload?

Answer (score 0):

Basically your webpage is being re-build to accomodate your landscape view of your mobile device
You can use this to keep it alive by the below code

Try this should work:

```
new WebviewScaffold(
          url: "https://flutter.dev/",
          withLocalStorage: true,
          withJavascript: true
      ),
```

Using this

```
withLocalStorage: true,
withJavascript: true
```

for your code to be alive

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm using webview_flutter plugin not flutter_webview_plugin, so there is no WebViewScaffold class in it, I should've been more clear, sorry again.